# How to divide a byte array into bit places

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

How can i store two numbers in a byte array or set the bits at diffrent positions?
like divide the array in two blocks.
one block of 5 bits and second of 3 positions.
so storing 6 and 3 would look like:

```
      num:            6                 3
      bit       7 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 || 2 - 1 - 0
      bin       0 - 0 - 1 - 1 - 0 || 0 - 1 - 1


      byte[] byte = new byte[1];

      int x = 6;  // bin 00000110
      int y = 3;  // bin 00000011

      byte[0] = (byte)(x >> 8)
      byte[0] = (byte)(y >> 2);
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift (left, not right!) by the amount needed to put the bottom bit into position, and or the results together:

```
byte[0] = (byte)((x<<3) | y);    // x needs to move 3 to make room for y
```

If there might be spurious bits, use a bitmask to clean up the number before shifting into position:

```
byte[0] = (byte)(((x&0x1F)<<3) | (y&0x3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assyming you store your information as such: xxxxxyyy

```
x = 31; //x must be between [0,31]  `000 11111`
y = 7;  //y must be between [0,7]   `00000 111`

z = (x << 3) | y;


x = (z & 0xF8) >> 3;
y = z & 0x07;
```

Comment: So you say: left shift X 3 places include Y ??

Comment: yes, left shifting 3 places, so you get `11111000` and bitwise-or with y.